# I have a Problem in my code, but I cant find it

Tags: c++

In the following code is an issue in line 37:

```
checker = (2021.0 * stod(speicher[i]) / (3.0 * stod(speicher[i]) - 2021.0);
```

and I dont know why.
I already cant find it.
Issue:

> C2059 (issue with syntax: ";")

I hope you can help me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

// lokale Variablen
int counter = 0;
std::vector<std::string> speicher;

bool check(std::string number)
{
    double checker;
    // check if integer or double
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < number.length(); ++j)
    {
        if (number[j] == '.' && number[0] != '-')
        {
            if (number[j + 1] == '0' && number[j + 2] == '0' && number[j + 3] == '0'
                && number[j + 4] == '0' && number[j + 5] == '0' && number[j + 6] == '0')
            {

                // check if number exists
                for (unsigned int g = 0; g < speicher.size(); ++g)
                {
                    if (speicher[g] == number)
                    {
                        speicher.erase(speicher.begin() + g);
                        
                    }
                }               

                // check if same constalation 
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < speicher.size(); ++i)
                {
                    for (unsigned int h = 0; h < speicher.size(); ++h)
                    {
                        checker = (2021.0 * stod(speicher[i]) / (3.0 * stod(speicher[i]) - 2021.0);

                        if (checker == stod(speicher[h]))
                        {
                            speicher.erase(speicher.begin() + i);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // test fine
                counter++;
                speicher.push_back(number);

                return true;                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message in the question

Comment: Look at the expression carefully and add `)` to proper place according to what you want to do. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: `C2059 (issue with syntax: ";")` is not the full error message. You need to find out how to see the actual compiler output. I am not fluent with fancy ides, so I cant tell you how unfortunately

Comment: Located not far from the Error List tab is the Output tab. The error list is an overview. It tries to present a sleek and sexy round-up of the problems with the program. The Output tab provides the full build output. It often has much better information because it isn't concerned with keeping the error message small. Sometimes it even gives hints.

Answer (score 4):

`checker = (2021.0 * stod(speicher[i]) / (3.0 * stod(speicher[i]) - 2021.0));`

You missed a `)`